# How to configure Bower with Bootstrap in Sails.js 0.10.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sails.js

I'm trying to create a new bower task in a Sails.js 0.10.x project.

This is what I have right now: 
/tasks/config/bower.js

```
 /**
 * Bower
 */
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('bower', {
        dev: {
            dest: '.tmp/public',
            js_dest: '.tmp/public/js',
            css_dest: '.tmp/public/styles',
            options: {}
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');
};
```

Then, I have: /tasks/register/bower.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('bower', [
        'bower:dev'
    ]);
};
```

Then, I changed /task/register/default.js adding bower.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['bower', 'compileAssets', 'linkAssets',  'watch']);
};
```

If I run `grunt bower:dev --verbose` I get this log:

```
Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task
Warning: Maximum call stack size exceeded Use --force to continue.
```

I've commited my current project in: 
https://github.com/luislobo/sailsjs10-bootstrap3-angular

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the cause, (can it be as both register and config files are configuring a "bower" task?) but I may suggest you to do the following that could resolve the issue:

You can get rid of /tasks/register/bower.js and change /tasks/register/compileAssets.js to add the bower:dev call

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
        'clean:dev',
        'jst:dev',
        'bower:dev',
        'less:dev',
        'copy:dev',
        'coffee:dev'
    ]);
};
```

Sounds good?

Comment: Well, yes, I made it work that way previously, I just want to do it the way it is supposed to work